# Redirect internally to higher directory

Tags: .htaccess

I have `example.org` and `foo.example.org` pointing to the same directory, `/var/www/html/`, and want `foo.example.org` to internally redirect to `/var/www/foo/` using **only *mod_rewrite***.

This is what I have so far, but no joy:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../foo/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This gets me 500s due to hitting the limit of 10 internal redirects, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the internal redirect loop is that your only RewriteCond is the host name check. The host name won't change after the internal redirect, and alas, will get triggered when the rules are parsed for the new request. You can solve this by adding a RewriteCond to check if the path already is set to the expected value (i.e. only rewrite requests with the path set to /var/www/html, and skip any other rewrite - as it has already been rewritten).

I'm going to suggest that it might be cleaner to do something like this through [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html), depending on your use case.

Comment: Definitely other options out there, will take moons to explain the reasons for my limitation.

Yep, you're right, it ends up redirecting to `/var/www/foo/var/www/foo/var/www/foo/var/www/foo/var/www/foo/` etc.

Any tips on what to put in as a condition?